# C++ Output Conversion Error

Tags: c++

I'm supposed to make a code that converts from feet and inches to meters and centimeters. But when I run my code, I don't get what I should get. For example, I input 1 foot and 0 centimeters. I should get 0.3048 meters and 0 centimeters but instead I'm getting 1 meters and 0 centimeters . Help!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void getLength(double& input1, double& input2);
void convert(double& variable1, double& variable2);
void showLengths(double output1, double output2);

int main()
{
    double feet, inches;
    char ans;

    do
    {
        getLength(feet, inches);
        convert(feet, inches);
        showLengths(feet, inches);

        cout << "Would you like to go again? (y/n)" << endl;
        cin >> ans;
        cout << endl;

    } while (ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y');
}

void getLength(double& input1, double& input2)
{
    cout << "What are the lengths in feet and inches? " << endl;
    cin >> input1 >> input2;
    cout << input1 << " feet and " << input2 << " inches is converted to ";
}

void convert (double& variable1, double& variable2)
{
    double meters = 0.3048, centimeters = 2.54;

    meters *= variable1;
    centimeters *= variable2;
}

void showLengths (double output1, double output2)
{
    cout << output1 << " meter(s) and " << output2 << " centimeter(s)" << endl;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: `meters *= variable1` is equivalent to `meters = meters * variable1`, i.e. you assign the result of the multiplication to `meters`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
meters *= variable1;
centimeters *= variable2;
```

should be

```
variable1 *= meters;
variable2 *= centimeters;
```

What the last comment said: you're not assigning the product to the variables that you've passed by reference (`variable1` and `variable2`), so those values are not changing from your original input of 1 and 0.

Comment: Any time my friend, glad to help